# Trigger WebBrowser.Close() from Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I am using `Watin` to run some tests on websites. What I think is missing is that I can't stop navigation on a browser from `Watin`. The `WebBrowser` control itself has has a `browser.Close()` method. Is there a way to trigger this from watins `IE` ?

In a test I need to stop browser from the site it is loading, and force it to load another url. The test environment contains a really long page and limited network speed. So the website takes long to load. I want to cancel it and make it navigate elsewhere.

Just using `browser.GoTo("http://testurl");` doesn't do the trick. Is there a way to stop browser from within the testing-thread?

(I don't want to throw an event from that thread and invoke `browser.close()` from the main thread.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably there are many ways to do this. This code shows how to do it with JavaScript.

```
string jsCode = "document.execCommand('Stop');\n" +
                "window.location='http://www.google.com.tr'";
browser.RunScript(jsCode);
```

Note that `document.execCommand('Stop')` is for IE, if you are using FF use `window.stop()`